# @trendmicro/react-sidenav JavaScript library in react typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I am trying use @trendmicro/react-sidenav JavaScript library in react typescript project. But, I don't find suitable *.d.ts file to add.

As index.d.ts file is not available for library it is giving error for following import.

import SideNav, { Toggle, Nav, NavItem, NavIcon, NavText } from '@trendmicro/react-sidenav';

Please assist with solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this library(version 0.5.0) seems does not have TypeScript type definition files. We can declare the [Shorthand ambient modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules) for it to pass the TSC type checking.

> If you don’t want to take the time to write out declarations before using a new module, you can use a shorthand declaration to get started quickly.

> All imports from a shorthand module will have the `any` type.

`src/@types/@trendmicro/react-sidenav/index.d.ts`:

```
declare module '@trendmicro/react-sidenav';
```

Add `./src/types` directory to [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) in `tsconfig.json`.

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015"
        ],
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./src/types"
        ]
    }
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76817958-ndvmxn)